# Animating position of radial gradient using framer moiton

Tags: html, css, reactjs, framer-motion

So I have this component which aims to add a sort of spotlight effect to a paragraph/text. I've used a `radial gradient` as the background image and `background clip text` to make the effect.

I wanted to animate it so the spotlight follows the cursor so I added the `handleMouseMove` function which sets the `useMotionValues`. Then I use the values in the style to adjust the X and Y of the gradient.

Everything seems to be working, however I'm stuck on making it animate smoothly. For example, when the cursor is not hovering anymore I wanted to move the spotlight back to the middle. I made the `handleMouseLeave` function which does move it back to the middle, but it snaps it instead of animating it.

**Some pics of the component (colors are changed)**

[image]

**In this second image I was hovering over the right end of the text, so the middle of the gradient (black) moved there**

[image]

**Code**

```js
const GradientBackgroundParagraph = ({ text }) => {
    let mouseX = useMotionValue(50);
    let mouseY = useMotionValue(50);

    const handleMouseMove = ({ clientX, clientY, currentTarget }) => {
        const { left, top, width, height } = currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();

        mouseX.set(((clientX - left) / width) * 100);
        mouseY.set(((clientY - top) / height) * 100);
    };

    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
        mouseX.set(50);
        mouseY.set(50);
    };

    return (
        <motion.p
            onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
            onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
            style={{
                backgroundImage: useMotionTemplate`radial-gradient(circle at ${mouseX}% ${mouseY}%, rgb(var(--foreground-rgb)), red)`,
                backgroundClip: "text",
            }}
            className="text-2xl bg-clip-text text-transparent cursor-default transition-all"
        >
            {text}
        </motion.p>
    );
};
```

**Update**:

Here is a gif with the effect to get a better idea
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone that may have the same question in the future, I figured it out and it was quite simple. All I did was change `useMotionValue` to `useSpring`. Everything else was kept the same and the effect is now animated.

Here is the final code: (Have done some cleanup, but the main part is the `useSpring` at the top)

```js
const GradientBackgroundParagraph = ({ text }) => {
    const mouseX = useMotionValue(50);
    const mouseY = useMotionValue(50);
    const mouseXSpring = useSpring(mouseX);
    const mouseYSpring = useSpring(mouseY);

    const handleMouseMove = ({ clientX, clientY, currentTarget }) => {
        const { left, top, width, height } = currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();

        mouseX.set(((clientX - left) / width) * 100);
        mouseY.set(((clientY - top) / height) * 100);
    };

    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
        mouseX.set(50);
        mouseY.set(50);
    };

    const spotlightBackground = useMotionTemplate`radial-gradient(circle at ${mouseXSpring}% ${mouseYSpring}%, rgb(var(--foreground-rgb)), transparent 150%)`;

    return (
        <motion.p
            onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
            onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
            style={{
                backgroundImage: spotlightBackground,
                backgroundClip: "text",
            }}
            className="text-2xl bg-clip-text text-transparent cursor-default"
        >
            {text}
        </motion.p>
    );
};
```